# Mudar diretorio default dos projetos feito em Zend 2

Tags: htaccess, zend-framework-2

Olá pessoal esse é meu primeiro post :D

Sou novo em Zend framework e estou usando o Zend 2 + PHP 5.5 + MySql + Apache

Tenho o sistema em meu servidor funcionando atraves do endereço http://localhost e não estou usando Virtual Host do Apache, estou usando somente o modo rewrite e arquivo .htaccess

O problema:

- Quero colocar mais um NOVO sistema no mesmo servidor onde poderia ser acessado através localhost/sistema1 e localhost/sistema2 porem toda mudança que tento até abre o sistema, mas quando tento acessar os menus ele sempre tenta usar o endereço localhost e não localhost/sistema1.

É como se o Zend tivesse algum lugar onde eu possa configurar qual é o diretorio raiz do projeto.

E mesmo se eu não usar os menus e digitar diretamente o url ele tb não funciona. Estou usando para menus o Zend Navigation.

OBS.: Não gostaria de usar Virtual Host, pois quando eu for hospedar o sistema em uma hospedagem geralmente eles não deixa vc mexer nas configurações do Apache.

Segue o .htaccess que estou colocando dentro de localhost/sistema1 :

```
# Turn on rewrites.
RewriteEngine on

# Only apply to URLs on this domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?localhost$

# Only apply to URLs that aren't already under folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/

# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all those to insert /folder.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

# Also redirect the root folder.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?localhost$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L]
```

- Gostaria tb se possível fazer com que os dois sistemas usasse o mesmo Zend, para não precisar ficar redundante o diretorio da Zend em TODOS os novos sistemas. Mas isso não é tão importante agora. Tenho urgencia em resolver o item anterior.

Obrigado pessoal e lembrem q sou novato no Zend então deem uma explicação um pouco mastigada. (mas no PHP mexo a muitos anos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consegui resolver o problema.

Vou postar aqui a solução caso alguém passar pelo mesmo problema no futuro.

A solução foi através do arquivo .htaccess, acrescentei no final do arquivo:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public
```

Com isso qualquer requisição feita dentro do diretório /sistema1 ou /sistema2 será redirecionado para o diretório public.

Dentro de public tem outro .htaccess que já vem com o skeleton do Zend, que faz todo o resto acontecer.

Meu .htaccess do diretório /sistema1 ficou assim:

```
# Turn on rewrites.
RewriteEngine on

## Only apply to URLs on this domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?localhost$
#
## Only apply to URLs that aren't already under folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
#
## Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#
## Rewrite all those to insert /folder.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

# Also redirect the root folder.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?localhost$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public
```

É obvio que quando for colocar em um domínio válido a palavra **localhost** deverá ser substituída pelo seu domínio.

Já o meu .htaccess do /public ficou assim: (isso já vem no Zend)

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Bem, no mais muito obrigado e agora com essa solução talvez eu consiga colocar até em uma hospedagem que eu uso no Locaweb ;)